# Drupal Commerce Kickstart 2 change variation and content types to modify way products are displayed

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

I'm learning Drupal Commerce with a Commerce Kickstart 2 installation. I've understood in part the way products are displayed, with variation types and content types.

Have made some changes like visible/hidden product fields, and change the order product fields are displayed. But didn't get how, for example, in

http://demo.commerceguys.com/ck/bags-cases/commerce-guys-laptop-bag

the bag stay positioned left side and others product fields right side.

I'm running Drupal 7 and Commerce Kickstart 2

I'd like to know how to define new positions for product fields in my drupal commerce site.

Answer (score 0):

The product page is displayed using the "Cloud Zoom" property. If you go to the manage display of the Product display type, you can find out more.

Comment: I've changed settings for "Cloud Zoom" property, but without success. The image remains below the other fields.

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot of "Manage Display" of your product and product variation type.

Comment: Thanks for comments @Chithra. Now the things are better. The problem was that I've chosen Image as a field for my variation type, rather than Images. Apparently the css for Image render the image in same column as the other fields, and for Images, the image(s) go left side. All that is for Commerce Kickstart theme. As I achieve what I wanted, I'll not worry for now. Thanks again.